# Realloc invalid next size

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define max_cadena 100

int main(int argc, char* argv){

    //variables 
    int  n = 0;
    float acumulated = 0;
    float average = 0;
    int flag = 1;
    int numberMajor = 0;
    int numberMinor = 0;
    int size = 5;

    //Separa un array de 20 bytes
    int *array = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    if ( array == NULL){
        exit(0);
    }

    while(flag){

        //variables
        
        char buffer[80];
        const char *compare = "x\n";

        printf("ingrese su numero\n");
        fgets(buffer, max_cadena, stdin); //obtiene la cadena ingresada
        if (strcmp(buffer,compare) == 0){ //compara si es una X
            flag = 0;
        }
        int number = atoi(buffer); //convierte la cadena a un entero
        acumulated += number;
        
        *(array+n) = number; // asigno a cada espacio de mi arreglo el numero ingresado desde consola

        if ((size - 1) == n){ // valido si el tamano de mi arreglo menos 1 es igual al contador para duplicar mi arreglo
            size = size *2;
            array = realloc(array,size * sizeof(int));
            memset(array+size,0, size * sizeof(int));
        }




        if (number > numberMajor){
            numberMajor = number;
        }
        else if (number < numberMinor){
            numberMinor = number;
        }
        n++;

        printf("El mayor  es: %d\n", numberMajor);
        printf("El menor  es: %d\n", numberMinor);
        printf("El acumulado es: %f\n", acumulated);

        
    }
    // promedio 
    average = acumulated/n-1;
    printf("La cantidad de numeros ingresados es %d\n", n-1);
    printf("El promedio es %.2f\n", average);
    printf("Finalizo el programa correctamente\n");
    exit(-1);
}
```

Estoy haciendo un programa que aumenta el tamano de un arreglo pero al final el programa termina porque Realloc invalid next size. Cada vez que el array se llene yo estoy aumentando al doble el espacio que ya habia y sigo guardando mas elementos hasta que mi usuario ingrese por consola la x. Al finalizar mi programa deberia poder calcular la desviacion estandar pero esa es una funcion que aun no completo.
Segun mis calculos mis direcciones de memoria son correctas.

Comment: Dos cosas. 1) El segundo argumento de main tiene que ser `char *argv[]`. 2)
Probando tu codigo con el ASAN, al ingresar el quinto numero me indica que
tienes un `heap-buffer-overflow`.

Comment: Es necesario que sea así? Sino puedes usar un vector.